# applying exponents in an absolute value brackets

Tags: exponential-function, absolute-value

So part of the problem I'm trying to solve is this:

$|2-9|^{3{^3}}$ being the exponent, to the power of 3.

Do I have to apply the exponent to everything in the bracket? 2*2*2 and 9*9*9 or does the absolute value bracket work like a parenthesis does in Pemdas and apply the exponent to the sum inside of the parenthesis after it's calculated?

Comment: "Absolute value" takes precedence in such an expression.

Comment: The absolute value bars have the same precedence has other grouping symbols such as parentheses or brackets.

Answer (score 1):

This is why everyone should learn GEMS: Groupings, exponenents, multiplication, subtraction/addition instead of PEMDAS. The expression in the absolute value is a grouping.